# pipe or redirect output from curl to ssh command

Tags: ssh, curl, macos, json, jq

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but I have been wrong in the past.

Basically, what I'd like to do is take the JSON output from a curl command and pipe it to jq for prettiness.  Which works fine.  Except OSX doesn't have it and has to be installed through brew or other means.  Not a problem for me.  But in the corporate setting, installing 3rd party apps is frowned upon.  But our plethora of Linux servers have jq installed.

Is it possible to pipe the local output to ssh to run jq on?

`curl https://whatever.site/json | ssh linuxHost "jq '.'" > output.json`

Caveat is that the plethora of Linux servers don't have external access, so running the curl command there doesn't work.  Yes, I could do an scp, but that's more steps.

Comment: "Is it possible to pipe the local output to ssh to run jq on?" Yes, absolutely. Have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Assuming both the https request and the ssh connection work properly, yes this should work. For _some_ dataformats using curl output directly on Unix (including both MacOS and Linux) can be problematic because web (and earlier MIME) transmission mostly uses CRLF linebreaks where Unix tools expect only LF, but Javascript and thus JSON ignores linebreaks.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to *pretty-print* JSON documents (no fancy filtering, aggregation, or what have you), then you could use `json_pp` (`/usr/bin/json_pp`), which is a simpler utility found amongst the macOS base system utilities.  The `json_pp` utility is a command line wrapper around the `JSON::PP` Perl module.

```bash
$ echo '{ "hello": "world!" }' | json_pp
{
   "hello" : "world!"
}
```

See `man json_pp` for instructions on customising the output format (the `-json_opt` option).

Example:

```bash
$ echo '{ "hello": "world!" }' | json_pp -json_opt pretty,indent_length=2,space_before=0
{
  "hello": "world!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you run `ssh` with a command, `ssh` enters the `rsh` (as opposed to `rlogin`) mode whereby instead of running the login shell of the user on the remote system in a pseudo-terminal, `sshd` runs the specified command with stdin, stdout and stderr connected to three different pipes.

And the contents of those pipes are transmitted over the encrypted tunnel and  read/written from/to the stdin, stdout and stderr of the `ssh` process¹.

So in:

```
local-cmd | ssh 'remote-cmd' > file
```

- `ssh`'s stdin is the reading of the pipe `local-cmd` is writing to
- `ssh`'s stdout is the `file` open in write-only mode.
- `ssh`'s stderr is likely a terminal device if you ran that from a terminal

And

- what `ssh` reads from stdin is sent over the encrypted channel and fed to `remote-cmd` through a pipe.
- What `remote-cmd` writes over there on stdout to a pipe is sent over the encrypted channel by `sshd` (which is reading from the other end of that pipe) and `ssh` upon reception writes it to its stdout, so to the file.
- Same for `remote-cmd`'s stderr on a separate pipe.

You can observe it with lsof:

```
$ sleep 3 | ((sleep 1; lsof -wc ssh -ad 0-99 +E >&2) <&- & ssh root@127.0.0.1 'lsof -wp "$$" -ad 0-2 +E; sleep 2') > file
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
screen   7561 chazelas    9u   CHR    5,2      0t0      89 /dev/ptmx ->/dev/pts/5 63562,zsh,0u 63562,zsh,1u 63562,zsh,2u 63562,zsh,10u 63608,sleep,0u 63608,sleep,2u 63609,ssh,2u 63609,ssh,6u 63610,lsof,1u 63610,lsof,2u
sleep   63608 chazelas    1w  FIFO   0,14      0t0  698683 pipe 63609,ssh,0r 63609,ssh,4r
ssh     63609 chazelas    0r  FIFO   0,14      0t0  698683 pipe 63608,sleep,1w 63609,ssh,4r
ssh     63609 chazelas    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0       5 /dev/null
ssh     63609 chazelas    2u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5 7561,screen,9u
ssh     63609 chazelas    3u  IPv4 697921      0t0     TCP localhost:50006->localhost:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
ssh     63609 chazelas    4r  FIFO   0,14      0t0  698683 pipe 63608,sleep,1w 63609,ssh,0r
ssh     63609 chazelas    5w   REG   0,39      540 8488375 /home/chazelas/file
ssh     63609 chazelas    6u   CHR  136,5      0t0       8 /dev/pts/5 7561,screen,9u
~$ cat file
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
sshd    63612 root    5w  FIFO   0,14      0t0 698269 pipe 63692,bash,0r 63695,lsof,0r
sshd    63612 root    7r  FIFO   0,14      0t0 698270 pipe 63692,bash,1w 63695,lsof,1w
sshd    63612 root   10r  FIFO   0,14      0t0 698271 pipe 63692,bash,2w 63695,lsof,2w
bash    63692 root    0r  FIFO   0,14      0t0 698269 pipe 63612,sshd,5w
bash    63692 root    1w  FIFO   0,14      0t0 698270 pipe 63612,sshd,7r
bash    63692 root    2w  FIFO   0,14      0t0 698271 pipe 63612,sshd,10r
```

Where you can see `ssh`'s fd 4 and 5 (duplicated from fds 0 and 1¹) going to the pipe from sleep and `file` respectively, and on the remote side (the output of `lsof` there ends up in `file`) fds 0, 1, 2 of the remote shell are 3 different pipes all going to `sshd`.

So, that way, when it comes to standard IO, running `ssh cmd` is functionally similar to running `cmd` locally, but still with some important points to note:

- as seen above, `cmd`'s stdin/stdout/stderr on the remote systems are pipes, regardless of what they are for `ssh` on the client (like pipe, regular files and tty device respectively in our example). For instance, without the redirection to `file`, you'd notice that `jq`'s output is not in colour as `jq` only colours its output when it goes to a tty device.
- `ssh` will consume the output on its stdin and send it to sshd regardless of whether `cmd` on the remote host reads it, so for instance `seq 1000 | (ssh localhost 'IFS= read -r one_line_only'; cat)` outputs nothing because even though the remote `read` command only reads one line, `ssh` has sent the full output of `seq` to `sshd` (most of why was not read by `read`), so `cat` has nothing left to read.

Here, you could also do:

```
curl... | ssh 'jq . > remotefile'
```

Where the output of the remote `jq` is stored in a remote file (in the home directory of the remote user). Or:

```
curl... | ssh 'jq . | tee remotefile' > localfile
```

(or simply `curl | ssh 'jq >&1 > remotefile' > localfile` if the login shell of the remote user is zsh) for the output to `jq` to be stored both locally and remotely.

---

<sup>¹ In the case of openssh at least, [stdin and stdout are duplicated on a different fd](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_9_7_P1/ssh.c#L1976C7-L1976C9) which are the ones being used and [stdout is reopened on `/dev/null`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_9_7_P1/ssh.c#L2286), but that's an implementation detail and makes no difference in practice.</sup>